# Dictionary of list of dictionary c#

Tags: c#, string, list, dictionary

I want dictionary of list of dictionary like this :

```
Dictionary <string, List<Dictionary<string,string>> field;
```

But visual studio send me error :

> Error CS0305  Using the generic type 'Dictionary' requires 2

How can solve this error (or a better solution for my problem)?

Comment: Complex data structures like this are probably better represented by a class!

Comment: Definitely use a class - however looking at your code you are missing a closing > character in the definition. `Dictionary <string, List<Dictionary<string,string>>> filed;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing a bracket at the end:

```
Dictionary <string, List<Dictionary<string,string>>> field;
```

Answer (score 5):

***TL;DR: You are missing a `>` in the end of the decleration, but you should use a better solution***

You should try to avoid complex data structures which involve generic types inside other generic types and so on and create you own `class` instead.

For example:

A `Dictionary` from the name of a guy to `Dictionary` of phone companies he is a member of to a phone number he has in each company will look like:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> nameToCompanyToNumber;
```

And following what's going on is more difficult than creating custom `classes` which are more readable:

```
class Person
{
    Dictionary<string, string> companyToNumber;

    public string GetPhone(string company)
    {
        return companyToNumber[company];
    }
}
```

This will make your code more clear:

```
List<Person> people;
people.First().GetPhone("AT&T");
```

Instead of:

```
nameToCompanyToNumber["SomePerson"]["AT&T"];
```

Which will require you to try to understand what is going on every time and will make the code harder to maintain, ***this is what OOP is all about***.

As for your compilation error, you are missing a `>` in the end:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string,string>>> field;
```

Answer (score 4):

Dictionaries like this work. Although it seems you are missing a closing > which probably causes your problem.

Thus:

```
Dictionary <string, List<Dictionary<string,string>> field;
```

Should be:

```
Dictionary <string, List<Dictionary<string,string>>> field;
```

One thing though from experience. If you have such complex data types and it is not something quick and dirty you should reconsider things and think about using a class instead.

At least later on a class will be way more maintainable and less confusing than such a complex dictionary (not only later on, but also if someone else has to modify your code).